# Why is the text overlapping the image at large break point

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

this code is supposed to keep the lorem ipsum text in the center at all times but instead, when I reach the large breakpoint it overlaps the image. Please explain why this is happening and how to fix it. here is the code so far (please excuse the fact that the background is white, that was stack overflow acting up):

```css
body {
    background-color: pink;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

#mainNav {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 100;
}
#mainNav #navLinks {
    color:white;
}

#mainNav #navLinks:hover {
    color:#EA1C2C;
}

#mainNav .navbar-brand{
    color:#EA1C2C;
}

#MoC span {
    color:#EA1C2C
}

#MoC h1 {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 4rem;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
    #MoC h1{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="candy.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Museum of Candy</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8d084e6dec.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md py-0 fixed-top">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">CANDY</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="navLinks">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="navLinks">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="navLinks">TICKETS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid px-0">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div id="MoC" class="text-white text-center d-none d-lg-block mt-5">
                    <h1>MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
                    <h1>MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
                    <h1>MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
                    <h1>MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
                    <h1>MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
                    <h1>MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
                    <h1>MUSEUM<span>/</span>OF<span>/</span>CANDY</h1>
                </div> <!-- MoC collapse  -->
            </div> <!-- column collapse  -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534073737927-85f1ebff1f5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="gloved hand holding a donut">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- row collapse  -->
    </div> <!-- container collapse  -->
    
    <div class="container-fluid px-0">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 img-fluid">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525059337994-6f2a1311b4d4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=654&q=80" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-candy-cane"></i>
                <h2>MUSEUM OF CANDY</h2>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor odio, inventore vitae debitis sint hic ut consectetur quia, ex quo, sit in quam voluptas ab tenetur? Architecto exercitationem qui cupiditate, dignissimos voluptatum, nesciunt adipisci animi minima odio deserunt ullam atque aperiam repudiandae, distinctio omnis necessitatibus aut pariatur suscipit maiores fugiat dolore magni praesentium. Sit illo, amet, dolore repellendus magnam quisquam, maxime voluptates non incidunt repudiandae autem fugiat minima quod. Vero!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you image is problem. you should add image max-width:100%;

**css**

```
img{
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```